# Mingw-64 with Netbeans ( Unable to start correctly 0xc000007cb)

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, netbeans-7, mingw-w64

I followed this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478317/netbeans-and-mingw-w64) to install mingw-64 with Netbeans, When I run the application I always get the below error. What would be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Either you're missing the various needed libraries in path, like libgcc and libstdc++, or you're mixing 32bit libraries with 64bit application. For the first you should add the mingw-w64 libray path to the environment path.

Comment: +1 thanks for the response.I have already added the mingw-w64 path to the PATH.

Comment: So, if you're absolutely sure that path is valid to where libstdc++.dll and the other libraries are located, then you need to check if there are some mix of 32bit and 64bit libraries - to do that, you could use objdump - but dependency walker is probably easier.