# Install gcc 4.9 on windows and configure it in Netbeans

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, netbeans-8

**Preamble**

If anything I wrote is not correct, please be so kind and correct me. I am a php developer mainly - I am not into this compiling stuff. I know there are a lot of topics around the www but they seems to be either old/outdated, very complex or links to a bunch of files on sourceforge (I have no clue what files I should download and what to do with them after downloading them).

**Searching a couple of days by now**

I am researching for a couple of days by now and tried different compilers and settings but I don't get a standalone executable for a c++14 programme.

**First compiler**

The first compiler I used was cygwin. I was able to compile it with c++14 but on other computers cygwin had to be installed as well as a cygwin dll was missing. I googled and figured out that programmes compiled using Cygwin requires this dll but cannot be included to the programme itself - or did I missed something?

**Current compiler**

I then switched to MinGW which seems to be a better choice as it allows to compile standalone executables which is correct as I am able to do so. Well, the MinGW setup I downloaded from http://www.mingw.org/ installed among other the gcc version 4.8.1. I need 4.9.1 for c++14.

As the title says I want to configure it in Netbeans but if there is a proper tutorial for a command line compiling it's no problem either but I try to avoid using another IDE as we use it at work, too.

**drangon.org**

I also heard about http://www.drangon.org/mingw/ but there are tons of links linking to similiar stuff.

**My goals**

1. Get a better understanding about gcc and this compiling stuff in general.
2. Install gcc 4.9.1 (preferred into MinGW as it's currently installed)
3. Configure it in Netbeans 8.

Comment: You can get a fairly recent, complete, and extremely easy to deploy compilation of MingW from [nuwen.net](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll take a look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Due to time consuming tests of the suggest by HolyBlackCat I did not test it yet.

Comment: Don't feel obliged to update me. You can use the information you get here in any way you like without strings attached.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php). ([Download.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download))

It's similar to MinGW, but have better multitreading support, can easily compile x64 applications, and what's more important, at this moment it uses GCC 4.9.2.

---

By the way, MinGW applications require some `.dll`s to work too. Usually you just provide these libraries with your application, but another option is to add `-static` flag at linking phase. Applications that are compiled with it do not require any external library files (unless you're using 3rd party libraries that don't support static linking).

Comment: You'd better be more explicit about `mingw-builds dwarf thread-posix` build, because by your link a lot of builds mentioned.

Comment: HolyBlackCat's: Thanks for your response. I'll take a look into it tomorrow. Yeah, you're right. I added -static to the add. command line commands in Netbeans. Lol4to: What's dwarf thread-posix?

Comment: @AMartinNo1 He's talking about different options from the installer. They determine what specific version of MinGW-w64 you will get. Afaik, Lol4to suggested one of the popular combinations.

Comment: Sensible linking options are `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to link the GCC-specific libraries statically. No need to link everything statically (which isn't even possible in every case).

Comment: Hm, it's not working. I have installed [MinGW-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download) with version 4.9.2, i686 as architechture, posix as thread and dwarf as exception. I also downloaded msys and extracted it to local c:/msys. My reference setup up guide was http://stackoverflow.com/a/13530554/3904215

Comment: And my Netbeans configuration: http://data.tesconic.com/mingw-w64-compile-error.png PATH var: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\msys\bin;C:\mingw-w64\i686-4.9.2-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2\mingw32\bin`

Comment: @AMartinNo1 Oops, have not noticed that bottom part. I have no idea what's wrong, I never used this IDE. You can try `mingw32-make.exe` from `mingw32\bin` instead of your `make.exe`, it may work.

Comment: I will check it on thursday.