# how to add c++ iostream into the scope of SCC?

Tags: c++, ide, iostream

I'm starting to learn c++ and found that for some reason my IDE cant open iostream and spawns the example hello world snippet with

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
```

on the top instead. But I know that `stdio` is a part of C std and is used when the c++ std is out of scope? Should I install additional packages somehow? the compiler I use is SCC and my IDE is Plato x32.

Thank you very much in advance :)

P.S. I found a lot of tutorials on package installation but mostly for MinGW, and none for SCC.

Comment: SCC stands for Simple C Compiler, meaning you don't have a C++ compiler.  What are you actually trying to do?  Are you writing code for hardware embedded hardware?

Comment: @NathanOliver No - I'm literally trying to figure out how to set up C++ learning environment without vs code, and somehow the following snippet https://commie.io/#F2PRgFjy compiles with SCC, and it was generated from c++ app stub

Comment: That code in your link is C code, not C++.  You cannot compile C++ code with SCC.  What OS are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm on windows 10. I tried installing MinGW with c++ capabilities but I didn't figure out how to force Plato to use it

Comment: I can't help you with that, but that is what you need to do if you want to compile C++ code.  Is there a reason you don't use MSVS?  If you are okay using the Netbeans IDE, you can get that to work with mingw64 shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478317/netbeans-and-mingw-w64

Comment: thanks - that's perfect,  MSVS keeps on wrecking my other projects on installation don't know y

Comment: This easily can be correct C++ code, it has many from C.